# I want to get a value of an object from an array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have a service which gives me data such as this. Im trying to build a commenting feature.

```
 students:
   { id: string; 
    isEdit: boolean; 
    userName: any; 
    userBio: any;
   profileImage: any; }[];
```

Now I'm trying to get the value of userName, something like Object.values but only userName.

```
addComment(){
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.comments.push(this.comment);
    let data = {
    comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion
    ({comment: this.comment, username: Object.values(this.students) })
    }
    this.firebaseService.updatePost(this.item.id,data)

  }
```

the above code results in this 
[image],

How can I just get to upload the value of username? 
so I can have { comment: "sdd", username: "snfs"}, as opposed to uploading all of the object?

I have tried this.students.userName but i get the error Property 'userName' does not exist on type '{ id: string; isEdit: boolean; userName: any; userBio: any; profileImage: any; }[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `this.students.userName` instead of `Object.values(this.students)`.

Comment: I have tried this but i get the following error " Property 'userName' does not exist on type '{ id: string; isEdit: boolean; userName: any; userBio: any; profileImage: any; }[]"

Comment: @catcat Is your `this.students` a list? In this case, you would have to use `this.students[0].userName` but you have to beware if the length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
students:
    { id: string;
      isEdit: boolean; 
      userName: any; 
      userBio: any;
      profileImage: any; }[];
```

are you sure you have this kind of structure because it contains a lot of error what does `;` semicolons are doing here and what role `[]` brackets are playing here.

if your syntax is correct please provide the full reference of `students`